# Linux software raid assembled "itself" with failed drive. Why?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have two raid1 arrays: md3 (sda3 + sdb3) and md5 (sda5 + sdb5).

I deliberately failed the sdb disks because I wanted to change the partition table:

```
# mdadm /dev/md3 --fail /dev/sdb3
# mdadm /dev/md5 --fail /dev/sdb5
```

Some time later I checked /proc/mdstat and it says

```
Personalities : [raid1] md5 : active raid1 sdb5[1]
      104792064 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]

md3 : active raid1 sda3[0]
      52396032 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

**So although I failed sdb5, md5 was assembled with sdb5 instead of sda5. How could this happen?**

I am using mdadm v3.3 and kernel is 3.14.3-200.fc20.x86_64